# How do I automatically run "cargo fix" on save in VSCode?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

- Currently, I use VSCode as my IDE when programming Rust.
- I use the `rust-analyzer` VSCode extension, since it seems to be the best one out there for Rust (as of 2022).

I have the following two entries in my "settings.json" for VSCode:

```
{
  "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command": "clippy",

  "[rust]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  },
}
```

- This makes it so that `clippy` (the linter) runs automatically upon pressing Ctrl + s to save the file.
- It also makes it so that `rustfmt` (the formatter) runs automatically upon pressing Ctrl + s to save the file.

In addition to these two things, I also want `cargo fix` to run automatically upon pressing Ctrl + s to save the file, because doing that automatically cleans up unused imports.

How can I accomplish this?

(I want unused imports to be automatically cleaned up for the same reason that I want an automatic formatter. Manually removing unused imports is tedium and a complete waste of my time in the same way that manually adding the appropriate amount of tabs or spaces is.)

Answer (score 8):

Clippy has a `--fix` option, that applies the suggested fixes automatically. So all you need is to change the the on-save check command. However, you need two arguments `clippy` and `--fix`, and for that you cannot use `rust-analyzer.check.command` and have to override the full command:

```json
{
  "rust-analyzer.check.overrideCommand": [
    "cargo",
    "clippy",
    "--fix",
    "--workspace",
    "--message-format=json",
    "--all-targets",
    "--allow-dirty"
  ],
}
```

Beware, however, that it will apply all automatically-applicable suggestions, not just remove unused imports.

All of these flags are what rust-analyzer automatically adds to `rust-analyzer.check.command`, but when you use `rust-analyzer.check.overrideCommand` you have to specify them yourself. Here's a short description of them ([the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-check.html) has more details):

- `--workspace` - apply the command to all members in the Cargo workspace, and not just one package.
- `--message-format=json` - emit JSON as a response instead of human-readable output, so that rust-analyzer can analyze the response and show the errors.
- `--all-targets` - check all things, i.e. binaries, libraries, examples, tests and benchmarks.
- `--allow-dirty` - fix even if workspace has changes.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what all of the flags do and why they are necessary beyond just adding "--fix"?

Comment: Also, I get the following error message when adding this: `cargo check failed: Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" }: `

Comment: @James Edited to explain. About the error, it probably means `rustc` isn't found. Try executing this command (`cargo clippy --fix --workspace --all-targets`) from the command line. What is the output?

Comment: Output is normal, e.g. "Checking", then "Finished" in 2.21s. To be clear, when I use the settings in the OP, everything works just fine in VSCode, its only when I change it does it fail to find Clippy. I'm on a pretty normal Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm.. Strange. If you set the setting `rust-analyzer.server.extraEnv` to `{ "RA_LOG": "flycheck=info" }` (I think you need to restart VSCode), then save, and open the Output>Rust Analyzer Language Server panel, you should see something (or multiple instances of) beginning with `[INFO flycheck] restart flycheck` what in this line (with your original setup)?

Comment: Ok, I did that. Unfortunately, the output panel isn't super helpful. All it says is: `[INFO flycheck] restart flycheck "cargo" "clippy" "--fix" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--all-targets"
[ERROR flycheck] Flycheck failed to run the following command: "cargo" "clippy" "--fix" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--all-targets"`

Comment: No, do that without my configuration, with your original configuration that does not include the `--fix`.

Comment: With the configuration from the OP I get the following output: `[INFO flycheck] restart flycheck "cargo" "clippy" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--manifest-path" "d:\\Repositories\\isaac-save-installer\\Cargo.toml" "--all-targets"`

Comment: If you add the `"--manifest-path", "d:\\Repositories\\isaac-save-installer\\Cargo.toml"` to the settings, does it work?

Comment: No: `[INFO flycheck] restart flycheck "cargo" "clippy" "--fix" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--all-targets" "--manifest-path" "d:\\Repositories\\isaac-save-installer\\Cargo.toml"
[ERROR flycheck] Flycheck failed to run the following command: "cargo" "clippy" "--fix" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--all-targets" "--manifest-path" "d:\\Repositories\\isaac-save-installer\\Cargo.toml"`

Comment: Oh, I see the reason, it's because I have to add --allow-dirty. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer appears to be out of date but can be fixed by using `rust-analyzer.cargo.buildScripts.overrideCommand` instead of `analyzer.checkOnSave.overrideCommand`.

Comment: @happybeing The name was changed to `rust-analyzer.check.overrideCommand`. Fixed, thanks.